Create view with working hours based on data
I've got a table:



Employee_id
Date
Time
Type




630
02.01.2024
09:45:50
IN


630
02.01.2024
17:02:40
OUT


630
13.02.2024
16:06:30
OUT


630
17.09.2024
06:37:50
IN


630
17.09.2024
08:07:30
OUT


630
17.09.2024
08:21:00
IN


630
17.09.2024
16:20:00
OUT



For each employee_id and each date I need to find IN and OUT pairs.
If there's pair IN and OUT return IN and OUT in pair-rows. In my example theres going to be one row for 02.01.2024 but two rows for 17.09.2024 and it means that employee left company in middle of the day.
There's also case that he forgot to Clock in or clock out. Then I need to add proper description to new column.
What I want to achieve is basically something like that.



Employee_id
Date
IN
OUT
DESCRIPTION




630
02.01.2024 00:00:00
09:45:50
17:02:40



630
13.02.2024 00:00:00
null
16:06:30
NOT CLOCKED IN


630
17.09.2024 00:00:00
06:37:50
08:07:30



630
17.09.2024 00:00:00
08:21:00
16:20:00




I've tried to do write query myself but failed.
That's my code I tried:
WITH CTE_Start AS (
    SELECT 
        Data,
        Employee_id,
        Time,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_id, Data ORDER BY Time) AS RW
    FROM 
        logs
    WHERE 
        Type = 'IN'
),
CTE_Stop AS (
    SELECT 
        Data,
        Employee_id,
        Time,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_id, Data ORDER BY Time) AS RW
    FROM 
        logs
    WHERE 
        Type = 'OUT'
),
Base AS (
    SELECT 
        Data,
        Employee_id
    FROM 
        logs
    GROUP BY 
        Data,
        Employee_id
)
SELECT 
    p.Data,
    p.Employee_id,
    start.Time AS start,
    stop.Time AS stop,
    CASE 
        WHEN start.Time IS NOT NULL AND stop.Time IS NOT NULL THEN 
            DATEDIFF(SECOND, 
                     CAST(p.Data AS DATETIME) + CAST(start.Time AS DATETIME), 
                     CAST(p.Data AS DATETIME) + CAST(stop.Time AS DATETIME))
        ELSE 
            NULL
    END AS Praca_sekund,
    CASE 
        WHEN start.Time IS NOT NULL AND stop.Time IS NULL THEN 'Brak WYJŚCIE'
        WHEN start.Time IS NULL AND stop.Time IS NOT NULL THEN 'Brak WEJŚCIE'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Praca_blad
FROM 
    Base p
LEFT JOIN 
    CTE_start start ON p.Data = start.Data AND p.Employee_id = start.Employee_id
LEFT JOIN 
    CTE_stop stop ON p.Data = stop.Data AND p.Employee_id = stop.Employee_id AND stop.RW = start.RW

There's almost what I want to achieve but if there isn't any IN type then it doesn't return stop time because I make a join on row_number column.

Can you also show us your current query attempt?

@jarlh Added code to post

Are the only possible values IN and OUT? Why are you storing date and time separately?

@AaronBertrand yep, there's only IN and OUT possible. Data is seperately cause thats the way someone created table. I just want to make use of it.

Can there be more than 2 rows per day? Frankly, this exact question has been asked at least a couple of times this year from my memory, why not search for it?

This question is similar to: SQL Server calculating working hours with multiple IN OUT. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@siggemannen Yep, there could more than two rows per day.
Before I posted a question I tried to find answer but didn't find anything

It isn't clear exactly when you want to see in the date/time columns when the employee hasn't clocked out (maybe you want both IN rows?), but this should get you close, given this sample data:
CREATE TABLE #logs
(
  Employee_id int, 
  [Date]      date, 
  [Time]      time,
  [Type]      varchar(3)
);

INSERT #logs VALUES
(630, '20240102', '09:45:50', 'IN' ),
(630, '20240102', '17:02:40', 'OUT'),
(630, '20240213', '16:06:30', 'OUT'),
(630, '20240917', '06:37:50', 'IN' ),
(630, '20240917', '08:07:30', 'OUT'),
(630, '20240917', '08:21:00', 'IN' ),
(630, '20240917', '16:20:00', 'OUT'),
(630, '20240918', '09:44:00', 'IN' ),
(630, '20240918', '13:57:00', 'IN' );

A series of CTEs to avoid repetition as much as possible:
WITH sensible_datetime AS
(
  SELECT *, proper_time = CONVERT(datetime, 
            DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, time), 
            CONVERT(datetime, date)))
  FROM #logs
),
paired_with_previous AS 
(
  SELECT *, prev_time = LAG(proper_time, 1) OVER 
                        (PARTITION BY Employee_id ORDER BY proper_time),
            prev_type = LAG([Type], 1)      OVER 
                        (PARTITION BY Employee_id ORDER BY proper_time)
  FROM sensible_datetime
),
final AS 
(
  SELECT *, dir = CASE [Type] WHEN prev_type THEN [Type] END 
   FROM paired_with_previous 
  WHERE prev_time IS NOT NULL
    AND (([Type] = 'OUT' AND prev_type = 'IN') OR ([Type] = prev_type))
)
SELECT Employee_id, 
       [Date] = CONVERT(date,    
                CASE dir WHEN 'IN' THEN prev_time ELSE proper_time END),
       [In]   = CONVERT(time(0), 
                CASE dir WHEN 'OUT' THEN NULL ELSE prev_time END),
       [Out]  = CONVERT(time(0), 
                CASE dir WHEN 'IN'  THEN NULL ELSE proper_time END),
       [Description] = COALESCE('NOT CLOCKED ' + CASE dir WHEN 'IN' THEN 'OUT'
                                                 WHEN 'OUT' THEN 'IN' END, '')
  FROM final
 ORDER BY Employee_id, [Date], [In], [Out];

Output:



Employee_id
Date
IN
OUT
DESCRIPTION




630
2024-01-02
09:45:50
17:02:40



630
2024-02-13
NULL
16:06:30
NOT CLOCKED IN


630
2024-09-17
06:37:50
08:07:30



630
2024-09-17
08:21:00
16:20:00



630
2024-09-18
09:44:00
NULL
NOT CLOCKED OUT




SQL Fiddle


it might be done with an outer apply, like this example
select t.employee_id, 
       t.[date], 
       t.[time] as [IN], 
       out.[time] as OUT, 
       case when t.[time] is null then 'not clocked in' 
            when out.[time] is null then 'not clocked out' 
            else null 
       end as description
from   ( select t.employee_id, 
                t.[date], 
                case when t.type = 'IN' then t.[time] else null end as [time],
                row_number() over (partition by employee_id, [date] order by employee_id, [date]) as rw
         from   table1 t
       ) t  
  outer apply ( select top 1 
                       t1.[time]
                from   table1 t1
                where  t1.employee_id = t.employee_id
                and    t1.[date] = t.[date]
                and    t1.type = 'OUT'
                order by t1.employee_id, t1.[date], t.[time] desc
              ) out
where t.rw % 2 <> 0;

see this dbfiddle
output is



employee_id
date
IN
OUT
description




630
2024-01-02
09:45:50.0000000
17:02:40.0000000
NULL


630
2024-02-13
NULL
16:06:30.0000000
not clocked in


630
2024-09-17
06:37:50.0000000
08:07:30.0000000
NULL


630
2024-09-17
08:21:00.0000000
08:07:30.0000000
NULL


630
2024-09-18
13:57:00.0000000
NULL
not clocked out




You can implement your logic directly using lag() and lead() functions.
See example
CREATE TABLE logs (Employee_id int, Date date, Time time, Type varchar(3));
INSERT logs VALUES
(630, '2024-01-02', '09:45:50', 'IN' ),
(630, '2024-01-02', '17:02:40', 'OUT'),
(630, '2024-02-13', '16:06:30', 'OUT'),
(630, '2024-09-17', '06:37:50', 'IN' ),
(630, '2024-09-17', '08:07:30', 'OUT'),
(630, '2024-09-17', '08:21:00', 'IN' ),
(630, '2024-09-17', '16:20:00', 'OUT'),
(630, '2024-09-18', '09:44:00', 'IN' ),
(630, '2024-09-18', '13:57:00', 'IN' );
create index ix_employee_date_time on logs(Employee_id,date,time)include(type);

Query
select Employee_id,Date, in_time,out_time,new_type -- add comments for new_type
from(
 select * 
  ,case when type='IN' and next_type='OUT' then 'IN-OUT'
        when type='IN' and (next_type='IN' or next_type is null) then 'IN-' 
        when type='OUT' and (prev_type='OUT' or prev_type is null) then '-OUT' 
   else 'OUT' 
   end new_type
  ,case when type='IN' then time 
   end in_time
  ,case when type='IN' and next_type='OUT' then next_time
        when type='OUT' then time
   end out_time
 from(
   select * 
     ,lag(l.Type)over(partition by l.Employee_id,l.Date order by l.Time) prev_type
     ,lead(l.Type)over(partition by l.Employee_id,l.Date order by l.Time) next_type
     ,lead(l.Time)over(partition by l.Employee_id,l.Date order by l.Time) next_time
   from logs l
  )t1
)t2
where new_type in('IN-OUT','IN-','-OUT')
order by Employee_id,date,time




Employee_id
Date
in_time
out_time
new_type




630
2024-01-02
09:45:50.0000000
17:02:40.0000000
IN-OUT


630
2024-02-13
null
16:06:30.0000000
-OUT


630
2024-09-17
06:37:50.0000000
08:07:30.0000000
IN-OUT


630
2024-09-17
08:21:00.0000000
16:20:00.0000000
IN-OUT


630
2024-09-18
09:44:00.0000000
null
IN-


630
2024-09-18
13:57:00.0000000
null
IN-



fiddle

Hello this is another way in which you can do this, solving each in_time and out_time separately:
WITH log_in AS (
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_ID, date ORDER BY date) AS RN_LOG_IN
    FROM logs 
    WHERE TYPE = 'in'
), 
log_out AS (
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_ID, date ORDER BY date) AS RN_LOG_OUT
    FROM logs 
    WHERE TYPE = 'out'
), 
inside AS (
    SELECT logs.employee_id, 
           logs.date, 
           CASE 
               WHEN logs.type = 'out' AND log_in.type IS NULL THEN NULL 
               ELSE logs.time 
           END AS inside,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY logs.employee_id ORDER BY logs.date) AS rn
    FROM logs 
    LEFT JOIN LOG_IN 
        ON logs.employee_ID = LOG_IN.employee_ID 
        AND logs.date = log_in.date
        AND log_in.RN_LOG_IN = 1 
    WHERE logs.type = 'in' 
       OR log_in.type IS NULL
), 
outside AS (
    SELECT logs.employee_id, 
           logs.date,
           CASE 
               WHEN logs.type = 'in' AND log_out.type IS NULL THEN NULL 
               ELSE logs.time 
           END AS outside, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY logs.employee_id ORDER BY logs.date) AS rn1
    FROM logs 
    LEFT JOIN LOG_OUT 
        ON logs.employee_ID = LOG_OUT.employee_ID 
        AND logs.date = log_out.date
        AND log_out.RN_LOG_OUT = 1 
    WHERE logs.type = 'out' 
       OR log_out.type IS NULL
) 
SELECT inside.Employee_id, 
       inside.Date,  
       inside.inside AS in_time, 
       outside.outside AS out_time ,
case when inside.inside is null then 'NOT CLOCKED IN' 
     when outside.outside is null then 'NOT CLOCKED OUT' else '' 
END as description
FROM inside 
JOIN outside 
    ON inside.employee_id = outside.employee_id 
    AND inside.rn = outside.rn1
ORDER BY inside.Date;

Hope it helps.
